How to change Base Map/Map Type with custom control in Leaflet?
I created custom bar as image below:

This my HTML code:

<div class="collapse map-custombar-collapse-left" id="listMapBaseControl">
    <ul class="ul-map-custombar-collapse-left">
        <li class="li-map-custombar-collapse-left">
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiomaptype" id="mapTypeToOSM" value="osm" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="mapTypeToOSM">OSM Map</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="li-map-custombar-collapse-left">
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiomaptype" id="mapTypeToStreet" value="streetmap">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="mapTypeToStreet">Google Street</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="li-map-custombar-collapse-left">
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiomaptype" id="mapTypeToTraffic" value="trafficmap">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="mapTypeToTraffic">Google Traffic</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="li-map-custombar-collapse-left">
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiomaptype" id="mapTypeToSatellite" value="satellitemap">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="mapTypeToSatellite">Satellite Map</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="li-map-custombar-collapse-left">
            <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiomaptype" id="mapTypeToHybrid" value="hybridmap">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="mapTypeToHybrid">Hybrid Map</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>

and, this my JS Code:

var googleStreets = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});

var googleHybrid = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});

var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}',{
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains:['mt0','mt1','mt2','mt3']
});

var googleTraffic = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@221097413,traffic&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom: 2,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
});

var osm = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
});

var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [-5.368029,112.005921],
    zoom: 5,
    layers: [osm]
});

var baseMaps = {
    "OSM": osm,
    "Street": googleStreets,
    "Traffic": googleTraffic,
    "Satellite": googleSat,
    "Hybrid": googleHybrid
};

var overlays =  {//add any overlays here
};

//var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlays,{position:'bottomleft'}).addTo(map); Hidden default control

$('input[type=radio][name=radiomaptype]').on('change', function() {
  switch ($(this).val()) {
    case 'osm':
      baseMaps["OSM"].addTo(map);
      break;
    case 'streetmap':
      baseMaps["Street"].addTo(map);
      break;
    case 'trafficmap':
      baseMaps["Traffic"].addTo(map);
      break;
    case 'satellitemap':
      baseMaps["Satellite"].addTo(map);
      break;
    case 'hybridmap':
      baseMaps["Hybrid"].addTo(map);
      break;
    
    default:
      baseMaps["OSM"].addTo(map);
      break;
  }
});

I have 2 issues:

Example, last selected position on radio "Satellite Map", when I reload the page, the map type changes to default type which is "OSM", but on the radio still selected/checked is "Satellite Map" although I set default checked is for "OSM" in the HTML code above.

When page first loads, first try to change map type is success, but on the second try, changing map type is not working.


Example:

Page open
Select "Google Sat" radio. Map will change to "Google Sat" -  successful
Select "Google Hybrid radio, and map will change to "Google Hybrid" - successful
Select "Google Sat" radio again, and map fail to change.

I'm still learning about Leaflet and need help
PS: If using default layer control from Leaflet, I didn't encounter the issues.


first, you must clear your map and add a new TileLayer. The leaflet has a separate state from your application.
You can use this code to clear them out:
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.TileLayer) {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
});

I must add that this is not a good way to remove your layers. because if you have a huge bunch of layers it might have some performance issues. The best way is to just use:
map.removeLayer(currentTileLayer);

after this, you can add your preferred layers as you've done before.
for the issue with RadioButton being checked or unchecked, You can store your current state into query params or localstorage

Hi, interesting with this:
map.removeLayer(currentTileLayer);
How I define/call "currentTileLayer?"
I'm still learning about Leaflet and need more help for more understanding about this.

@dvaa you can save your selected tileLayer into a variable and remove it in subsequent access. or you can define arrays of some tileLayers and then access them through the array index saved in query params.

Hi, back to you again...I give the condition in each case, as below example.
case 'satellitemap':    map.addLayer(googleSat)     if(map.hasLayer(osm)){     map.removeLayer(osm);     } else if(map.hasLayer(googleStreets)){     map.removeLayer(googleStreets);     } else if(map.hasLayer(googleTraffic)){     map.removeLayer(googleTraffic);     } else if(map.hasLayer(googleHybrid)){     map.removeLayer(googleHybrid);  };   //baseMaps["Satellite"].addTo(map);         break;
And its work. How do you think? Is it okay method?

@dvaa yes, but you can make it simplified.
const tiles = [osm, googleStreets, googleTraffic,  googleHybrid];
tiles.map((tileLayer) => {
if(map.hasLayer(tileLayer)) {
map.removeLayer(tileLayer);
}
} and If your issue has resolved I'd be grateful that you mark it as solved. tnx

Solved! Have nice day!
